# Understanding Python Function Call - Various Outputs

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I have a function which is defined as below,

```
import pprint

class Test(object):
        def __str__(self):
                return "at __str__"

        def __repr__(self):
                return "at __repr__"

x = Test()

print x
pprint.pprint(x)
```

Output:

```
at __str__
at __repr__
```

Questions:

1. what "**def __str__(self):**" representation means.
2. Why the first print is printing the first return value where as
   pprint is returning second return value.

I'm pretty new to python programming, appreciate if you can provide more detailed information on this.

Comment: Isn't this code kind of self-explanatory? You have just demonstrated that `print` calls the object's `__str__` while `pprint.pprint` calls the object's `__repr__`.

Answer (score 1):

[Difference between **str** and **repr** in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) is perfect answer of your question if you only want to know about `__str__`.but i suppose you may really want to know what is mean. It's called Operator Overloading.you can implement`__abs__`,then you can `-x`.read[Operator Overloading question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Operator%20Overloading%20%5Bpython%5D)

Comment: great reference... thank you :)